# How to set Genaral onCLick for Views in XML layout in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My application  have 17 **ImageButtons** which each of them has an animal image and if user clicks on it .That animal voice played for user.

As I said I have 17 ImageButtons .if I want to set **OnClickListener** for each of them .I have to write `button.setOnCLickListenr(/*implementation*/);` or `button.setOnCLickListenr(this);*` (within implementing View.OnCLickLIstener interface)     **17 times** .

My buttons are not near to themselves and so  I can not use **RecyclerView**, **ListView** or **GridLayout**.

Is there any way to decrease the number of OnClickListener from 17 times to lower. or just use **setOnClickListener** method once

Thanks...

Comment: You can call same method in `android:onClick=yourMethodName` for each button. and in your method you can check the view id.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Butterknife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library, check example:

```
@OnClick({ R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3 })
public void onClicked(View view) {
   // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create one OnClickListener and set it to all your ImageViews.

Example:

```
public OnClickListener onClickListener {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
      // Identify every imageview by its id 

   } 
}


imageview1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
imageview2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
imageview3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
```

Comment: @AlirezaBideli You should set this listener to all your imagebuttons, There is no another way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this instead of creating an inner class in every onclick

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
       int i = v.getId();
        switch (i){
            case R.id.btn1 :
                break;
            case R.id.btn2 :
                break;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Of course Your solution is better than implementing onClickListener as anonymous inner class but again I have to write setOnClickLIstener(this) 17 times . I want to decrease the number of OnClickListener an make my code cleaner

Comment: I have some other thing in my mind I will post it in some time... :)